# Is it possible to buy Taj Mahal tickets at the spot instead of online?

Tags: tickets, india, bookings, sightseeing, agra

I've been reading sites, and I know that it's possible to buy tickets to visit Taj Mahal in advance online, but is it possible to buy tickets at the spot - in Agra (using cash)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to buy tickets on the spot. As [official website of Taj Mahal](https://www.tajmahal.gov.in/ticketing.html) show outlets from which you can buy tickets.

> Ticket Outlets 
>   (Buying a Taj Mahal Ticket From Entry Gate Ticket Counter)
>
> 1. Taj Mahal Western Gate :- Tickets are available on Western Gate near
>      Saheli Burj. (Timing-from Sunrise to Sunset).
> 2. Taj Mahal Eastern Gate :- Tickets are available at Shilpgram (about
>      750 meters from Eastern Gate of Taj Mahal. (Timing-from Sunrise to
>      Sunset).
> 3. Taj Mahal Southern Gate :- Tickets are available on Southern Gate.
>      (Timing - 8:00 A.M. To 5:00 P.M.)
>
> Tickets may be purchased at all three Taj Mahal entry gates. There are separate queues for Foreign tourists and Domestic tourists and signs will direct you accordingly.